# In Android Navigation Architecture, how can I check if current Fragment is the last one?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, android-navigation, onbackpressed

I need to display custom `AlertDialog`, but only when there are no more fragments after calling `NavController.navigateUp()`. My current code does something similar, but there is a bug to it:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {

    if (navController.navigateUp()) {
        return
    }

    showQuitDialog()
}
```

This somewhat works, but if I cancel the `AlertDialog` and don't quit the app, `navController` already navigated up to `NavGraph` root, which is not the fragment in which I was when `AlertDialog` appeared. So, if I try to use any navigation action from that fragment, I get error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination
>   com.example.test/actionNavigateToNextFragment is unknown to this NavController

This could be resolved, if I had access to `mBackStack` field in `NavController`, but it's `package private`, and I can't use reflection in my current project. But if it was `public`, I would use it the following way:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {

    // 2 because first one is NavGraph, second one is last fragment on the stack
    if(navController.mBackStack.size > 2) { 
        navController.navigateUp()
        return
    }

    showQuitDialog()
}
```

Is there a way to do this without reflection?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can compare the ID of the start destination with the ID of the current destination. Something like:

```
override fun onBackPressed() = when {
    navController.graph.startDestination == navController.currentDestination?.id -> showQuitDialog()
    else -> super.onBackPressed()
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Try this for any destination (you can find your destination id in the navigation graph):

```
private fun isDesiredDestination(): Boolean {
    return with(navController) {
        currentDestination == graph[R.id.yourDestinationId]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Comparing IDs of destination may not be the best solution because you can have multiple screens with the same ID but different arguments on the backstack.

Here's an alternative:

```kotlin
val isRootScreen = navController.previousBackStackEntry == null
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want this is a button so to speak you can have this

```
yourbutton.setOnClickListener {
            val currentFragment = navController.currentDestination?.id
           when (navController.graph.startDestination == currentFragment) {
                true ->  { //Go here}
                 // Go to the app home
                else -> onBackPressed()
            }
        }
```